# View returns null to a controller, accepting ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with my controller. It accepts null.

First of all I've got such ViewModel

```
public class FilmVM
{
    public Film Film { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Image> Images { get; set; } = new List<Image>();
    public IEnumerable<SimilarFilm> SimilarFilms { get; set; } = new List<SimilarFilm>();
}
```

Controller looks like

```
public ActionResult Edit(FilmVM film)
{
    _unitOfWork.Film.Update(film);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Index action looks like

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    int pageSize = Constaints.Constaint.FilmsCount;
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    var films = _unitOfWork.Film.GetDatas();

    return View(films.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Models in VM are defaults like Guid, name, etc.

View model looks like

```
@model GuessTheMovieApp.ViewModels.FilmVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Edit</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Films", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-edit-film" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Editing Film</h4>
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.Partial("EditFilm", Model.Film)

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group__input">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Partial View looks like

```
@model GuessTheMovieApp.Models.DataBase.Film
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Film</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FilmId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Year, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

they are common, I think.

I saw similar question on stackoverflow, but it didn't helped me. So I'm asking if someone knows an answer on such question, please help.

UPD

Figured out how to work with this by changing Action Edit to this format

```
public ActionResult Edit(Film films, IEnumerable<Image> images, IEnumerable<SimilarFilm> similarFilms)
{
     _unitOfWork.Film.Update(new FilmVM { Film = films, Images = images, SimilarFilms = similarFilms });
     _unitOfWork.Save();

     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Do you call `_unitOfWork.Film.saveChanges`  after `_unitOfWork.Film.Update(film);` ?

Comment: More info, please: Are you actually saving the data (`.SaveChanges()`); Can you show us your `Index` action method (the one redirected to from the `Edit` action)?

Comment: Sure thing I'll add saving data, but for now it useless, 'cause in controller I have null Film model, after saving data in form

Comment: Updated question by adding Index action

Answer (score 0):

try to use the same model for view, partial view and action. You can use FilmVm as well as any another model. For example you can use Film in this case

```
@model GuessTheMovieApp.ViewModels.Film

.....

  <partial name="EditFilm" />

......
```

and action

```
[HttpPost]  
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  
public ActionResult Edit(Film film)
{
    var filmVm= new FilmVm { Film=film}
  .....
}
```

Comment: This could be a solution, but I need that type of model and changing that to film won’t help me in doing the app. I want to add to other views images and similar films.

Comment: @YehorKarachetsev  The only way to make it working to make the same model. You can use FilmVm as well. It is just  less to redo if you use Film.

Comment: Well, @Serge your answer pushed me to some solution of my problem, i don't know if I should accept it as answer, but I figured out how to work with that. So here's the code of Edit Action 
`
public ActionResult Edit(Film films, IEnumerable<Image> images, IEnumerable<SimilarFilm> similarFilms)
 {
            _unitOfWork.Film.Update(new FilmVM { Film = films, Images = images, SimilarFilms = similarFilms });
            _unitOfWork.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent your controller from accepting null at the parameter level, the best you can do is to do a null check on the object coming in before you call  your _unitofWork